# Fetch cookie set by header

Tags: php, cookies

I login to a website and it returns a cookie via the header.
The cookies name is fb_cookie. I try to read it with the below PHP code but it returns nothing. How can I fetch a cookie set via the header?

```
echo $_COOKIE["fb_cookie"];
```

The response is this from the header (read by the Poster plugin in Firefox).

```
fb_cookie=1554e662b9914b5d640d655f-627185705%7C6LneHfe-wWAworIG2hTHSzxuqkw.; path=/; expires=Thu, 07-Jul-2011 12:57:05 GMT _lambda_session=BAh7BzoMdXNlcl9pZGkBkToPc2Vzc2lvbl9pZCIlOGY2Y2U2ZDhlMDcyNTdjMDM4ZjYyNjQ4ZmU5OGU1ZTU%3D--3e60eb15a406a9320f7ab83fb7e0866198f4b6c7; path=/; HttpOnly
```

Please help!

Comment: Show the code which you use to retrieve the page.

Comment: I do not have the code unfortunately. The only code I use is the echo $_COOKIE["fb_cookie"]; and that should write out the cookie, or is there another way to echo cookies set in headers?

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve and echo cookies that are being fetched by your browser?

Comment: Mike B: Yes, I visit a page and login via Facebook Connect then I am redirected automatically to a blank page which creates a cookie with the code return by Facebook. It´s this cookie I then want to retrieve on my own page.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for wanting to hook into the browser and retrieve cookie values? As opposed to having the script do the login for you as suggested by Sjoerd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_COOKIE contains the cookies the user sends to your PHP page. You want the cookie which another page sends to you.

If you use curl to retrieve the page, the CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR option may help.

Comment: I will actually want to use the cookie in a CURL request. I know the cookie is set because if I hard code the name and value of the cookie it works fine to retreive information. curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'fb_cookie=1554e662b9914b5dfdd640d655f-627185705|6LneHfe-wWAworIG2hTHSzxuqkw.');